# Checking if element exists in XML file

Tags: c#, xml

I need to check if an element in XML file exists. After searching here, I have tried a code from one of very similiar questions I found here, so the code looks like this(it is looped using foreach so it checks every airport in group airports):

```
string icao = airport.Attributes.GetNamedItem("icao").Value;
            if(airports.SelectSingleNode("/vEsup/airports/airport/" + icao + "/departures")==null)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("I exist!");
            }
```

Please note that the message box is just for testing, I find it the easiest way to check if the code is working properly. However, I found out that whatever path I enter, it always shows the messagebox, regardless if it exist in the XML file or not.

Comment: if equals NULL then "I exist!"? It is strange.

Comment: Yes, that was a bit wrong. Anyway, it shows the box every time, it shows if it exists and if it doesnt, no difference...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use Linq to query specific xml nodes and attributes also.
Here is link to similar sample:
http://www.codearsenal.net/2012/07/c-sharp-load-xml-using-xlinq.html

Answer (score 0):

"shows the messagebox if it exist in the XML file or not." seems to be incorrect as you checking for node not to be present in XML `if (a.SelectSingleNode(...)==null)`.

Most likely you need to correctly specify namespaces to you nodes. (need sample XML to give any better suggestion)

Comment: This is the xml I am using: http://esup.ivao.cz/xml.php
from <airports> I get codes of all airports I need, and then I need to find out which of them contains <prilety> and which contains <odlety> (it can be both of them).

Answer (score 0):

In your 'if' block, aren't you checking to see IF the string is null?

My guess - and I could be wrong here - is that you meant:

```
    string icao = airport.Attributes.GetNamedItem("icao").Value;
        if(airports.SelectSingleNode("/vEsup/airports/airport/" + icao + "/departures")!=null)
        {
            return true;
        }
MessageBox.Show("I exist!");
```

Comment: well, but it shows the box both when it exist and if it doesnt, thats it

Comment: Okay, I have tried your code. With original "==null" it shows the box every time, now with "!=null", it doesnt show in any case.

Comment: I like Gregor's solution above much better than mine :)